# how to import XmlAccessorType in android

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to take a code from java to android (use android studio) that uses this imports:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlValue;
```

but it doesn't recognize this.
Does someone know how to import this in Android studio?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `jaxb-api-x.x.x.jar` on your android project classpath.

Try this [link](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api) for jar